# Stop video playing when web page is closed and start it again where it can be stoped

Tags: javascript, php, controls, video-streaming, html5-video

i need help in php website.i am create website like online videos courses.i need help in video module.if playing any video and close it after some time and again play this video then need to play it where it can be stop or closed.
This video are getting from database not embedded video.for showing video i am using afterglow video player.

```
<video class="afterglow" id="myvideo" height="385px" width="770px">
<source type="video/mp4" src="adminpanel/video/<?php echo $results->c_video; ?>"  />
</video>
```

Is there any script to solve this problem.

Comment: You have to store the information in some way. Its totally up to you how you do it. Use LocalStorage or maybe a PHP Session. Whatever you prefer. But SO is NOT a coding service . So please edit your question and show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: i have just use html video tag.no more than that.

Comment: Okay let me try to point you into the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments you have to save the position of your video somewhere. The most simple approach would be to use the localStorage. You can read more about localStorage in the official documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Storage

While the video is played the timestamp gets refreshed each second and the localStorage item is updated.

Then if you reload the page (remember: item still exists in the storage after a refresh) you check for its existence and set the video to the timestamp.

This should point you in the right direction.

```js
let video = document.getElementById("example");



if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty("time")) { //if time was set before adjust the video to it
 video.currentTime = localStorage.getItem("time");
}
let timer = setInterval(getTimestamp,1000);

function getTimestamp(){
  localStorage.setItem("time", video.currentTime);
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("time"));
}
```

```html
<video id="example" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="yoursourcefile" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```